# github merge from origin master on schedule

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

Some of our developers have multiple independent repositories they work off of.
We want the branches that they create for bug fixes and enhancements to get updates from the origin master every morning, automatically merge, and notify if there are any conflicts.

I think the command is

```
git merge [branchname]
```

but I want this to happen for every repo the developers have and have it happen every morning automatically.

Comment: This sounds a bit odd. So your developers have a clone of the repository, that is they have your main branch _master_ where they branch off to work on bug fixes. Later they merge back to their master branch and push to a centralized repository?

Comment: My opinion - don't do this. Better, teach/coach your developers to know when to do their own merges to fit into their own personal flow, and possibly institute some rules that require that they do it "at least so often". But, I would be very annoyed to come in some morning and find that the feature I was working on yesterday, that I flat-out knew wasn't anywhere near ready to merge yet, now has a bajillion merge conflicts that I have to spend the first half of my day resolving before I can get back to productive work...

Comment: We had planned on having a master(prd), QA(STG), and development branches for each ticket. Everyday, people would pull in changes from prd, but if we have spaced releases, there really isn't any point in that. The concern was to reduce merge hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't state strongly enough that every comment and your own self-answer in this thread will get you in trouble eventually. I'm not trying to stomp on anyone's toes, but this has bitten me many times before I finally learned how to do this properly. Anyone who issues a pull request to most organizations without first testing whether their own code conflicts with the parent repository's CURRENT state would find themselves quickly out of a job.

Best practices in any modern development team should generally proceed thusly:

1. Coder forks code from master repository
2. Coder adds an upstream remote to pull changes to the master repository into his own master branch.
3. Coder immediately makes a new feature/bug/hotfix branch in his own fork to have a pristine work environment to do his thing.
4. Either at regular intervals or before any pull requests are made, Coder pulls any upstream 
   changes to the master branch of his own fork.
5. Coder fixes any conflicts the changes to the master repository cause with his new feature/bug/hotfix.
6. Coder issues a pull request to the master repository.

If you just can't seem to grasp the basic concept of workflow, find something like gitflow to do the heavy lifting for you and you'll never look back. Those that you share code with will be most thankful if you follow something along these lines.

Comment: Great workflow, bad attitude. Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to stomp on your toes, but saying stuff like "find themselves out of a job" or "just can't seem to grasp" are phrases you want to avoid if you want to avoid stomping on toes. Either way, point taken, and I'll propose the workflow to my group.

Answer (score 0):

We decided that we will have developers get updates from origin master only after a release. After kicking the idea around, we agreed that getting the updates everyday would not be a good idea, or even necessary.